# SQL Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint, not adding foreign key

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a database I have been working on and I am trying to create another table however it keeps giving me the 1215 error, even though I am not adding foreign keys. Even a simple query like:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`Assignment` (

  `SomeNumber` INT NULL

)
```

will give me this result. Saving and restarting, and dropping all tables does not work... Suggestions?

Comment: can you post the structure for the table you want to create a foreignkey and the table where your foreign key will be referenced?

Comment: I actually removed all foreign keys out of frustration, so I am just trying to add basic tables back in right now without this error